# Jetpack Compose keep text aligned center after re-sizing

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I'm using a piece of code that auto-resizes the text font size if it's too big for current width of the text box, however as you can see the text doesn't stay central inside the text box. How can I keep the text in the center of text box? I've already used the textAlign argument as shown in my code below but no luck

```
    val textStyleBody1 = MaterialTheme.typography.body1
    var textStyle by remember { mutableStateOf(textStyleBody1) }

    Text(
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(60.dp)
            .height(20.dp),
        style = textStyle,
        text = playerName,
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
        softWrap = false,
        maxLines = 1,
        onTextLayout = {
            if (it.didOverflowWidth) {
                textStyle = textStyle.copy(fontSize = textStyle.fontSize * 0.9)
            }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: what do you mean it's not centered ?, I see it's centered with respect to the player t-shirt

Comment: Sorry, i mean as in it doesn't stay in line with the player next to it, my thought is that if the text is resizing, it should stay in the complete middle of the text box and get smaller, but appears to be pushed to the top of the text box

Comment: did you try making the text align attribute to horizontal + bottom ?

Comment: unfortunately there isn't an option for bottom with the textAlign arg

Comment: yes you're right I'm sorry, don't use the text align attribute then and try using the gravity, set the gravity to center_horizontal + bottom

Comment: Why not just make a custom modifier out of the `paddingFromBaseline` Modifier from the Layouts Codelab?